# Why are the grid-items so short in my css?

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm new to css...

Here's my problem: my grid boxes are so short that they are cutting off my code (I think that's what's happening). I have no idea why it's defining the grid box as so short?

(I would like long columns that adapt to the number of my divs, if possible.)

Any help would be so appreciated!!!

```
.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: .5fr 3fr 3fr .5fr;
    grid-gap: 20px;
    grid-template-areas: "header header header header"
    "sidebar content2 content sidebar2"
    "sidebar content2 content sidebar2"
    "sidebar content2 content sidebar2";
    height: 100vh;
    grid-column-gap: 150px;
    grid-row-gap: 80px;
}

.grid-item-1 {
    grid-area: header;
}


.grid-item-2 {
    background-image: url("brick.png");
    background-size: 300px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: relative;
    top: 70px;
    grid-area: content;
}


.grid-item-3 {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    display: grid;
    position: relative;

} 
.grid-item-01 {
    grid-area:sidebar;
}
.grid-item-0 {
    grid-area: sidebar2;
}
```

Comment: Please post the HTML, as well. We can better assist you when we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: Like @MichaelBenjamin suggested: Please post the HTML, as well. We can better assist you when we can reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, and thought I'd answer in case someone googles this and needs help.

I changed the height of each individual section to "height: auto".  Now my columns adjust automatically to whatever I add to them.  I'm not sure if this is the best solution... but it worked.